# problem with $refs value in bootstarp-vue b-input

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

while `this.$refs.my_input.value` works correctly with `<input>`, it returnd nothing wit `<b-input>`. this code:

```
<template>    
<b-input ref="my_input" @keyup.enter="AlertIt" />
</template>
```

script:

```
AlertIt() { alert(this.$refs.my_input.value) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should use `this.$refs.my_input._data.localValue` instead of `this.$refs.my_input.value`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `this.$refs['my_input']`

More info [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-input#exposed-input-properties-and-methods)

Comment: hi tommy, I tested that, didn`t work

Comment: What is the purpose of it? Maybe we can find an alternative for it!